# What are the reasons for using parser combinators?

Tags: parsing, haskell, parser-combinators

I'm looking at the [following approach](https://two-wrongs.com/parser-combinators-parsing-for-haskell-beginners) to using parser combinators in Haskell. The author gives the following example of Parser Combinators:

```
windSpeed :: String -> Maybe Int
windSpeed windInfo =
    parseMaybe windSpeedParser windInfo

windSpeedParser :: ReadP Int
windSpeedParser = do
    direction <- numbers 3
    speed <- numbers 2 <|> numbers 3
    unit <- string "KT" <|> string "MPS"
    return speed
```

The author gives the following reasons for this approach:

- easy to read (I agree with this)
- similar format to the specification ie the parser itself is basically a description of what it parses (I agree with this)

I can't help but feel I'm missing some of the reasons for choosing parser combinators. Some benefit of either [using](https://pchiusano.github.io/2016-09-15/static-vs-dynamic.html) Haskell, compile-time [guarantees](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/mwm/cards), [elimination](https://wiki.haskell.org/Hitchhikers_guide_to_Haskell#Chapter_2:_Parsing_the_input) of runtime errors. Or some subsequent benefit when you starting [parsing](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/06/you-could-have-invented-free-monads.html) DSLs [and using](https://joashc.github.io/posts/2015-09-13-free-monad-steps.html) free monads.

My question is: **What are the reasons for using parser combinators?**

Comment: Because data tends to be structured hierarchically, so you can write a parser for some subelement, and then build a cascade of parsers each doing one part of the puzzle? I.e. for an XML parser, first a parser that parses an attribute value, then a parser that parses `key="value"` using the previous parser, then repeat that parser to parse an arbitrary number of key/value-pairs, then parse a tag, then parse a tag hierarchy, etc.

Comment: I'd throw in the fact that you can reuse library functions, and that you're not limited to context-free grammars unlike a BNF-based approach.

Comment: Thanks-could you please expand that into an answer?

Comment: I think you can find answer here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/338665/when-to-use-a-parser-combinator-when-to-use-a-parser-generator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several benefits of using parser combinators:

- Parser combinators are a generalization of hand-written top-down parsers. In the case that you hand-write a parser, use parser combinators to abstract away common patterns.
- Unlike parser generators, parser combinators are potentially *dynamic*, allowing for decisions during runtime. This aspect may be useful if the language's grammar may be redefined based on the input.
- Parsers are first-class objects.